# Set Multiple Startup Projects in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, startup, visual-studio-mac

Is it possible/how do I set multiple start up projects in Visual Studio for Mac?

It is very easy and common to do it in VS for Windows (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx) but struggling to find the option on VS for Mac in the application and online.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this by creating a run configuration for the solution.

1. Select the solution in the Solution window and right click it and select Options.
2. Select Run - Configurations.
3. Click the New button and specify a name for the configuration.
4. Expand the Configurations on the left hand side and select the new run configuration just created from the left hand side.
5. Then check those projects you want to run when the solution is run.
6. Click OK to save the changes.

[image: Solution options]

Then in the main toolbar select the run configuration.

[image: Main toolbar]

Then when you debug/run both projects will be started.

Comment: Thank you Matt, exactly what I needed!

Comment: How about run order ?

Comment: There does not seem to be support for changing the run order in the solution options dialog but you can edit the .`vs/ProjectName/xs/UserPrefs.xml` file and change the order of the StartupItems in the MultiItemSolutionRunConfiguration section.

Comment: Wowsers.  That is a path and a half.  Yeah, I have a console app talking to my (local dev) rest service....(my two projects)....and the console is loading too fast for the rest service.  #needRunOrder . Upvote for this great detailed answer.